# Could a large amount of wget requests be viewed as an attack?

Tags: denial-of-service

I'm working on a program that downloads and analyzes historical stock data from Yahoo Finance. I download the data in my program by using the wget command. I have a list of about 3,000 stock symbols and the .csv files for each one are downloaded twice (for weekly and monthly data). Could Yahoo flag my large amount of wget requests as an attack? Maybe as a dos attack of some sort?

Comment: **Have you checked that yahoo doesn't have an API for this?**

Comment: Of course they could, however if you want to know if they do you will need to either ask Yahoo or read available documentation.

Comment: As far as I can find, this actually is the Yahoo API for finance data. The data is obtained by building URLs. I'll ask Yahoo and post their reply.

Comment: Found this question, which answers the question of Yahoo's request limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346582/what-is-the-query-limit-on-yahoos-finance-api

Comment: Actually the above link is likely the best answer. It details Yahoo limits from which one could establish compliance with is not a DOS attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is subjective but wget simply makes HTTP GET requests, just as is done with a browser.

At worst one might claim a denial of service (DOS) attack but if only a single thread, most would classify as either normal use or perhaps *aggressive* crawling.